# Why does single line text have new line?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have been using attributed text for `UILabel` of `UITableViewCell`.
Sometimes,even if text is single line but, text has new line.

My code is here

```
if notnullCheck(catchcopy){

                //行間
                let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: catchcopy!)
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
                attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

                self.catchcopyLabel.attributedText = attributedText


            }
            self.catchcopyLabel.sizeToFit()
```

The text height is 33 when multi line text is.
The text height is 14 when single line text is.
But sometimes, the text height is 19 when single line text is.
when line height is 19,the text has new line.

What is this problem?

The following text is debug log.

```
(98.0, 14.0)
勤務地表記確認

(230.0, 19.0)
ケイサイカキンなしんこうぃあ　02
```

Both texts are also single line.But height is not same.
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the frame size of your `self.catchcopyLabel `. Also, did you try with `[self.catchcopyLabel sizeToFit]`?

Comment: I already have used size to fit.I will update my question.

Comment: it's label size is 294*14 at xib file.

Comment: Sure, also a sample text string for both the case would also help!

Comment: Sure,i will update my question.

Comment: ...because each character's height is defined in the glyph, and they are not forced to be the same value in a font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using 'HiraKakuProN-W6' font and its size is 14.

It's not a matter of new line but of Japanese space character(全角スペース).

If you delete Japanese space character, you will get height of 14.

I have encountered this kind of strangeness since many years ago,

so I think it's BUG of HiraXXXXX-XX font.

Comment: OK,I will get rid of Japanese space character.